# Is there an error in the algorithm recording timestamps on SO?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, timestamps

Please look at the timestamps by Pegah and (others particularly in the comments to the question in this link:

[passing multidimensional arrays to function when the dimension size is not clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773157/passing-multidimensional-arrays-to-function-when-the-dimension-size-is-not-clear#comment5296993_4773157)

They are all at  Jan 24 '11 at 14:33:50 [Expand "show 15 more comments"]

How can even the seconds match by the same user on multiple comments. This looks spurious. Is there a general problem with the algorithm? I am posting this here so that stackoverflow developers may take a look. [I'm not sure this is the right place to post.] Or do you get timestamps from user's machine? In this case, it doesn't seem like that, for, even comments by other users have same timestamp recorded. So, this seems like a stackoverflow server error. I'm trying to do data analysis with timestamps and I am curious how often this happens?

If so, I should be careful while excluding duplicates just based on UserId and Post CreationDate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a deleted answer by the asker on that question, and all the comments with that date are also present on that answer. The answer was converted to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773157/passing-multidimensional-arrays-to-function-when-the-dimension-size-is-not-clear#comment5296989_4773157) alongside all of its comments; this is something that moderators can do. The answer-to-comment conversion resulted in a series of comments whose timestamp is the date of the conversion, rather than the date when the initial content was posted.

I'm not sure if this is really a bug — the timestamp *is* the date when the comment was created, after all. Even if it's a bug, it's a minor one, and it doesn't occur often (conversion of an answer to a comment is rare, and most of the time the comments aren't carried over).